# Adding value to Mailchimp subscriber group via api v2.0 with c#

Tags: c#, mailchimp

I have a group set up in mailchimp called 'Location' and I want to populate it with a string for each subscriber using the api and json with c#.  I have tried many things but I always get an internal server error 500 although I have successfully managed to subscribe users to the list so I know that the api is working with my setup.  I think the problem is with the way I am adding the groups but I don't know what it is.

```
 var url = https://us7.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Dictionary<string, string> merge_vars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> groupings = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> groups = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            data.Add("apikey", ApiKey);
            data.Add("id", ListId);
            data.Add("email", email);

            groups.Add("Location", "Test");
            groupings.Add("groups", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groups));
            merge_vars.Add("groupings", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupings));
            data.Add("merge_vars", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(merge_vars));

            var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailChimpMemberListsResponse>(client.UploadString(url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)));


        }
```